# Программа ничего не выводит(Java), в чем ошибка?

Tags: java

Новичок в Java, подскажите что не так?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class queue {
    int[] x = new int[10000000];
    int size=0;

    public void push(int a){
        x[size]=a;
        size++;
    }

    public void pop(){
        System.out.println(x[0]);
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            x[i]=x[i+1];
        }
        size--;
    }

    public boolean empty(){
        if(size==0)
        {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }


    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        queue f = new queue();
        String s;
        int n;
        while(in.hasNextLine())
        {
            s=in.nextLine();
            String[] l = s.split(" ");
            if(l[0]=="push")
            {
                n=Integer.parseInt(l[1]);
                f.push(n);
                System.out.println("ok");
            }
            if(s=="pop")
            {
                if(f.empty()==true)
                {
                    System.out.println("error");
                } else f.pop();
            }
            if(s=="front")
            {
                if(f.empty()==true)
                {
                    System.out.println("error");
                } else 
                System.out.println(f.x[0]);
            }   
            if(s=="size")
            {
                System.out.println(f.size);
            }
            if(s=="clear")
            {
                f.size=0;
                System.out.println("ok");
            }
            if(s=="exit")
            {
                System.out.println("bye");
                break;
            }
         }
    }
}
```